# My chat apps stopped working well only in my home!

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

My phone is Iphone 5s 11.4.1 and apps were working very well but suddenly chat apps (such as Facebook messenger, viber, telegram, etc) have stopped working well.
(I hear the voice of the other person yet the other person can not hear my voice).

The strange thing for me is that it just happens in my home, outside it everything runs so good.

Also Siri has the same problem, it does not hear me in my home!

In home I use my wifi network and sometimes my 4G. (They are from the same company)

I do not think that was because of the last update or whatever since the phone turns itself to work fine outside home using the 4G or any wifi network,  although it might coincides with a phone fell down but I am not remember well.

I do mot know what is going on. I live beside a police check point and my guess  is that the waves of their wireless devices have recently changed to have some sort of effect on my phone.

Actually, I do not know. Could anyone help on that. Thank you.

Comment: do you have some sort of Bluetooth device that could do that, like take over your audio.

Comment: Good point but not any bluetooth device I have Buscar.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Could you edit your question to clarify what you mean by *chat apps*? Can you provide a couple of examples? Also, if you can provide some additional info about your setup at home (e.g. are you using Wi-Fi, other Apple devices, etc) that may also be useful. Finally, is there anything you can think of that this *sudden* change coincides with (e.g. new router, software update, etc)?